# Setting a property from another property's setter from segue Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, setter

For reference, I'm trying to learn Objective-C through the Stanford iTunes-U course. I wanted to update one property from the setter of another (they are inherently connected. Also, is that bad style?). The property I am trying to update is a UILabel, but it doesn't work like I thought.
This code is in one of my view controllers:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [segue.destinationViewController setProgram:self.brain.program];
}
```

Naturally, this code calls the setter for the Program property of the incoming viewController. Here's that setter code:

```
-(void)setProgram:(id)program {
    _program = program;
    self.title = [CalculatorBrain descriptionOfProgram:program];
    [self.graphview setNeedsDisplay];
    self.testLabel.text = @"Trying to update your text!";
}
```

and the header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GraphViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) id program;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel;

@end
```

Now, when this code is run, as the segue happens, the new view DOES have its title changed (the self.title line works). However, the UILabel DOES NOT get updated. Furthermore, if I call the setter again say in viewDidLoad, it does change the UILabel. Is this because of `self` being updated? What's going on here?

Comment: Interesting, to the best of my knowledge your code should work as advertised. Since it's working in viewDidLoad I wonder if it's a quirk in how storyboards work. Put a break point in prepareForSegue, then in your destination view controller implement awakeFromNib with an NSLog and put a breakpoint there, then run your program and see what break point is hit first. If it's the awake from nib one then the problem is somewhere else, but if it breaks in prepareForSegue first then your view hasn't been unarchived from the storyboard yet meaning testLabel is nil when you set it.

Comment: also in this case I wouldn't worry about the setter style thing, this looks fine.

Comment: awakeFromNib is called when your view hierarchy is decompressed and assigned to your viewController. If prepareForSegue is called before awakeFromNib then the problem is that testLabel is nil. This can be fixed by putting your testlabel code in viewDidLoad. However if your looking to use the new Storyboard hotness then you might try putting it in performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: which should be called after the nib has been unarchived but before your destination view controller is presented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of the lectures, the professor explains that outlets aren't set yet in prepareForSegue. This means testLabel is nil, and you're sending a message to nil (which is allowed and doesn't crash your app). To solve your problem, set the textLabel's text in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

I believe this is "fixed" in iOS 6, but it won't be backwards compatible, so if you want to support iOS 5 still, you'll have to use viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear to update outlets (which I think is better to do anyway).

Comment: Helps to pay attention doesn't it.